# Have a table that includes startdate and durationminutes. Trying to get that to give new end date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Title says it all.

Table looks like this

```
Table: Time
First Column: startdate (shown as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
Second COlumn: durationminute (shown in minutes)
```

Since the above doesn't give me an end date, I'm trying to create a query which will do that.

I'm assuming this is going to be a dateadd function but I can't get it to work.  The durationminutes is a variable to is dependent on that one row so date_add(minutes, 30, startdate) wouldn't work as there is no constant.

I've tried

```
date_add(days, durationminutes/1440, startdate)
```

But am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL understands date arithmetics. Assuming that `startdate` is of `date` or `datetime` datatype (as it should be!), you can do:

```
select t.*,
    startdate + interval durationminute minute as enddate
from time t
```